# the same question 2 times

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I asked on [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), but then understood that I used a wrong site for this question, so I asked the same question on Mathematics, not aware that it was migrated from Mathematica.

So now I have 2 copy of the same question:

[migrated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800344/build-absolute-value-equations-know-solution)

and

[asked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800341/build-absolute-value-equations-know-solution)

I tried to delete migrated, but can't because it has answer, and I accepted it, because it's valid for Mathematica.

So, I think migrated question should be or deleted or migrated back.

Second question has 2 useful answers, so it should remain here.

Once again:

[this is valid question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800341/build-absolute-value-equations-know-solution)

[migrate or delete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800344/build-absolute-value-equations-know-solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software offers the option to mark the one question as a duplicate of the other. The posts will then be linked and all answers are preserved. I just cast a vote to that end. (I think you should be able to 'accept' this proposal when you visit the post.)

Since the questions are truly the same one could even ask moderators to merge the posts; this basically means that one would copy all the answers to one place.

Comment: okay, accepted as duplicate